# Recorded video path can't upload on server for iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, video, upload

Now I try to upload the record video path file on web server. But I'm facing some critical error when upload recorded video captured by device.

I have took the PBJVision custom video recording for recording options like Vine app. And I integrate into my app.

First I got the path value from PBJVision class file like this "/var/mobile/Applications/9C4A08BC-9190-4A37-A875-3077236731AB/Documents/13-11-2013||05:54:78.mp4".

Here I use NSDateFormat to identify make different videos.

Then I use trimming character functionality of the above path. then I change this path to a NSURL format.

Then I use the upload video path file using the below code,

```
 NSURL *urlvalue = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:self.videoPath];
    NSLog(@"The urlvalue is = %@",urlvalue);


    NSData *urldata = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:urlvalue];

     //NSURL *fileURL    =   [NSURL fileURLWithPath:videoPath];
     //NSLog(@"fileurl is = %@",fileURL);

     //NSData *videoData1 = [videoPath dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
     //NSData *videoData1=[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:videoPath];
    NSData *videoData1=urldata;
     //NSLog(@"URL FOR VIDEO = %@",videoData);
     NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [videoData1 length]];

     NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
     [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://demo.xyzxyzxyz.com/client/vine-clone/mobile/video_upload"]]];


     [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
     [request setTimeoutInterval:60000];


     NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449"];
     [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
     NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
     [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

     NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

     //video
     [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
     //[body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\"; filename=\"video.mp4\"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    //Video Name with Date-Time
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd-hh:mm:ssa"];
    NSString *currDate = [dateFormat stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"video-%@.mov\"\r\n", currDate];
    NSLog(@"String name::  %@",str);

    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:str] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

     //[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\"; filename=\"video.mp4\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
     //[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
     [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
     [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:videoData1]];
     //[body appendData:videoData];
     [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

     //set the body to the request
     [request setHTTPBody:body];

     // send the request
     NSError *error13;
     NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:&error13];

     if(error13 != nil)
     {
     NSLog(@"erro is = %@",error13);
     }

     NSLog(@"return data %@",returnData);
     NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

     NSLog(@"response from server is= %@",returnString);
```

Here I only get the result string is,

Nov 13 05:55:41 Lion-Users-iPod Vision[17484] : return data <0909>

Nov 13 05:55:41 Lion-Users-iPod Vision[17484] : response from server is=

I don't know why I got this empty value. Because the path was not an empty value, cause here before I used that path for show preview by using MPMoviePlayercontroller.

It was played nice. And I checked some video.mp4 file as a bundle and create a local path used above code. It was upload from both system compile and device using the above format.

Could you guide me for how to upload video file on the server and where i made mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Raman this is classic use case of IOS devices. Which don't let you access any Photo Album assets directly using path value. To cross check my answer please just check FileExistsAtPath for your file like below -:

```
println(NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath( urlvalue.path!))

O/P you will get => False
```

I also end up with this issue couple of days back After reading the whole IOS documentation. What I have figured it out "We can only access PhotoAlbum Assets if and only if we have PHImageManager session open". To cross check this statement please try below code -:

```
var currentVideofetch: PHFetchResult!
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    let options = PHFetchOptions()
    options.sortDescriptors = [
        NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: true)
    ]
    currentVideofetch = PHAsset.fetchAssetsWithMediaType(.Video, options: options)
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
func checkImageExists(){
let asset = self.currentVideofetch.objectAtIndex(1) as? PHAsset
}
if let checkedAsset = asset {
        PHImageManager.defaultManager().requestAVAssetForVideo(checkedAsset, options: nil, resultHandler: {[weak self](result: AVAsset!, audioMix: AVAudioMix!, info: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) in
            println(NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(self.urlvalue.path!))
            })
    }
O/P you will get => True
```

After opening the PHImageManager session and then when i tried accessing the video with the path. It worked fine. Also able to successfully upload all videos files in background using the relative path of videos in Photo Album.

If you need i can send you my implementation for this. But not sure if it is correct way or not. But working fine for me.

Hope it helps.